# How can I call a function from Gradle's `pluginManagement {}` block?

Tags: gradle

#### Introduction

Hi, I'm trying to deduplicate the code found in my app's `settings.gradle`. Here's what my file looks like currently:

```
pluginManagement {
    def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
    def properties = new Properties()
    assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }
    def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
    assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
    }
}

include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()
assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }
def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

(You can ignore the technology-specific things and why it has to be done like this – let's just assume *it has to be done like this*. If you're interested in more details, please see [this PR to Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/123511))

It's easy to see that the code responsible for loading `flutter.sdk` property from the `local.properties` file is duplicated twice. So I set out to remove this duplication.

#### Attempt 1 (variable)

At first, I tried the below code, only to be quickly reminded by Gradle that the "the pluginManagement {} block must appear before any other statements in the script."

```
def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()
assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }
def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"

pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
    }
}

include ':app'

apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

#### Attempt 2 (function)

The error message in the previous attempt says that no *statements* are allowed before the `pluginManagement {}` block. I thought about moving the code to a separate function, since, in my (modest) understanding, function isn't a statement in Groovy:

```
String flutterSdkPath() {
    def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
    def properties = new Properties()
    assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }
    def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
    assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
    return flutterSdkPath
}

pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
    }
}

include ':app'

apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

Unfortunately, it still doesn't work, and the error only got less helpful:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file '/Users/bartek/fvm/versions/master/examples/hello_world/android/settings.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> Could not get unknown property 'flutterSdkPath' for object of type org.gradle.plugin.management.internal.DefaultPluginManagementSpec.
```

I'm pretty sure it has to do something with how to `pluginManagement {}` block is treated by Gradle in a special way (that is, it's evaluated first, before the rest of code in `settings.gradle` is evaluated)

#### Attempt 3 (static method in a class)

I thought that maybe all code that's *before* the `pluginManagement {}` block is somehow stripped (?), so I tried creating a class with a static method in it:

```
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("${Flutter.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
    }
}

include ':app'

apply from: "${Flutter.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"

class Flutter {
    String flutterSdkPath() {
        def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
        def properties = new Properties()
        assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
        localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
}
```

This time the error message was even less helpful:

```
* Where:
Settings file '/Users/bartek/fvm/versions/master/examples/hello_world/android/settings.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> Flutter

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

After running Gradle with the `--stracktrace` flag, I noticed this line:

```
... (<very long stack trace>)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Flutter
...
```

Looks like the same problem that I encountered in attempt 2).

I have no more ideas on how to move the properties-loading code to a single place and call it from the inside of the `pluginManagement {}` block and from its outside.

I think a Gradle Settings Plugin could work here, but I'd prefer not to do it unless necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unfortunately, it still doesn’t work, and the error only got less helpful:

It says the property you try to reference is not found, as there is no such property anymore as you made it a method.

If you would instead try to call the method, it would tell you that the method is not found.

> I’m pretty sure it has to do something with how to `pluginManagement {}` block is treated by Gradle in a special way (that is, it’s evaluated first, before the rest of code in `settings.gradle` is evaluated)

Exact, it is extracted and evaluated separately.
The `pluginManagement` block can define plugin repositories or include builds with settings plugins, so to compile the rest of the script, it needs to be evaluated first separately.
Which is also the reason you cannot use properties or methods from outside the block.
It has to be self-contained.

> I thought that maybe all code that’s *before* the `pluginManagement {}` block is somehow stripped (?), so I tried creating a class with a static method in it:

As I said, all is "stripped", otherwise you could also simply define the method after the block and call it.

> I think a Gradle Settings Plugin could work here, but I’d prefer not to do it unless necessary.

No, it wouldn't help due to hen-and-egg problem.
settings plugins are evaluated after the `pluginManagement` block as that block can define included builds with settings plugins or repositories where to find settings plugins, so a settings plugin is too late to configure that block.

> PS I’d also happily accept an explanation as to why I got an error early in attempt 1), but not in attempt (2).

Not sure what you mean by "early", both errors come more or less immediately.
Just in attempt 1 you had statements before the block which is disallowed in Groovy DSL (it is allowed in Kotlin DSL but wouldn't work either to be used inside the block) and thus get an error while parsing the script to extract the block, while in attempt 2 you get an error when actually evaluating the block as it uses a property that does not exist.

---

You can do what you want to achieve by using "extra" properties.
Using them is usually a code-smell and a just a work-around for not doing something properly, but this might be one of the rare cases where its use might be appropriate.

While the `pluginManagment` block is evaluated separately standalone, it can still modify the model, so you can add a closure as extra property that is then also available to the remaining script:

```
pluginManagement {
    settings.ext.foo = { "Foo" }
    println("1: ${foo()}")
    includeBuild("${foo()}")
}

println("2: ${foo()}")
```

Answer (score 2):

**pluginManagement** block should only contain plugin-related configuration: declaring plugin versions, applying plugins, and configuring plugin repositories. The reason why it should be the first block is that it runs before other **gradle** files in your project. The purpose of this block it's not designed to be used for general-purpose scripting or importing other files.

There is no need to over-engineering. The functionality that you want to extract is simply fetching the variable from the `properties` file.

**Using `gradle.properties`**

create a file `gradle.properties` in the root of your project where the `settings.gradle` file is located and add:

```
flutterSdkPath=PATH_TO_YOUR_FLUTTER_SDK
```

In your `settings.gradle` you can use it:

```
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
    }
}

include ':app'

apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

For reference and more information on how to do it with Kotlin read [Plugin version management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_version_management)

**Using command line injection**

There are multiple ways on how to do it. Here you can read more about [Gradle, System, Environment, and Project properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html).
The hierarchy of them from high priority to low priority and how they'll override the values are:

1. Command line properties
2. System properties
3. Environment variables
4. `gradle.properties` in the home directory
5. `gradle.properties` in the project root directory

In short, you just need to pass the variable to your `gradle`
command via the command line

As a short example:

```
gradle -PflutterSdkPath=$(cat local.properties | grep flutterSdkPath | cut -d'=' -f2) <GRADLE_TASK>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem is that the existing tooling generates the `local.properties` file, and `flutter.sdk` is in that file, not in `gradle.properties`. Is it maybe possible to load Properties from a .properties file that is not `gradle.properties` in a similar, seamless way?

Comment: @BartekPacia, please take a look at the answer. I updated it with **command line injection** option

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer. Unfortunately, I don't think that passing the path as command-line flag manually on every build is feasible for us.

Comment: However, importing self-managed maven requires additional configuration of `pluginManagement`, although it is exactly the same as in `dependencyResolutionManagement`. I want to reduce them

Answer (score -1):

create a file gradle.properties in the root of your project

```
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).